# How to make fab visible when scroll up starting and hide when scroll down starting

Tags: java, android, android-coordinatorlayout, floating-action-button

I want to make fab hide as soon as scrolling down starting and show as soon as scrolling up starts how can I do this, right now I'm trying this but its appearing only when it reaches top and hiding when reaches bottom:

```
 @Override
public boolean onStartNestedScroll(final CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout, final FloatingActionButton child, final View directTargetChild, final View target, final int nestedScrollAxes) {
    // Ensure we react to vertical scrolling
    return nestedScrollAxes == ViewCompat.SCROLL_AXIS_VERTICAL
            || super.onStartNestedScroll(coordinatorLayout, child, directTargetChild, target, nestedScrollAxes);
}

@Override
public void onNestedScroll(final CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout, final FloatingActionButton child, final View target, final int dxConsumed, final int dyConsumed, final int dxUnconsumed, final int dyUnconsumed) {
    super.onNestedScroll(coordinatorLayout, child, target, dxConsumed, dyConsumed, dxUnconsumed, dyUnconsumed);

    if (CoordinatorLayout.SCROLL_INDICATOR_START == 16 && dyConsumed > 0 && child.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
        child.hide();
    } else if (CoordinatorLayout.SCROLL_INDICATOR_START == 16 && dyConsumed < 0 && child.getVisibility() != View.VISIBLE) {
        child.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you mean scrolling the entire screen?

Comment: yes the screen that has recyclerview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please do this way , I hope it will help for you.

```
 @Override
 public boolean onStartNestedScroll(final CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout, final View child,final View directTargetChild, final View target,final int nestedScrollAxes) {

// Ensure we react to vertical scrolling

 return nestedScrollAxes == ViewCompat.SCROLL_AXIS_VERTICAL
        || super.onStartNestedScroll(coordinatorLayout, child,
           directTargetChild, target, nestedScrollAxes);
 }

 @Override
 public void onNestedScroll(final CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout, final View child,final View target, final int dxConsumed, final int dyConsumed, final int dxUnconsumed, final int dyUnconsumed) {

 super.onNestedScroll(coordinatorLayout, child, target,dxConsumed, dyConsumed, dxUnconsumed, dyUnconsumed);
 if (dyConsumed > 0) {

  // User scrolled down -> hide the FAB

  List<View> dependencies = coordinatorLayout.getDependencies(child);
   for (View view : dependencies) {
     if (view instanceof FloatingActionButton) {
      ((FloatingActionButton) view).hide();
    }
  }
} else if (dyConsumed < 0) {
  // User scrolled up -> show the FAB
  List<View> dependencies = coordinatorLayout.getDependencies(child);
  for (View view : dependencies) {
    if (view instanceof FloatingActionButton) {
      ((FloatingActionButton) view).show();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: will this hide the fab as soon as scrolling down started

Comment: Yes, you will try out this.

Answer (score 2):

If there is a recyclerView in your layout this code will help you:

```
recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(object : RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        override fun onScrolled(recyclerView: RecyclerView?, dx: Int, dy: Int) {
            if (dy > 0) {
                fab?.hide()
            } else if (dy < 0) {
                fab?.show()
            }
        }
    })
```

Comment: but it will happen when i scroll down and stop then it will hide, i want it to hidden as soon as scroll down starts

Comment: This will hide the fab as soon as you start scrolling down